# How to generate uniq class ID which spend minimum bytes

Tags: c#

I'm developing a game and have serialization system, which can serialize primitives types in maximum compressed format if I needed(for example I can put 2 int values in 1 byte). I want to assign to each class which inherited of GameObject unique class ID to then transmit it over the network, i can use typeof(Type).Name but  that takes up so many bytes. How i can generate unique class id to each class so that it takes, for example, only 2 bits?

Comment: Probably off topic but why are you so concerned with saving so much space? It sounds like premature optimisation.

Comment: 2 bits meaning - 4 possibles id's not very unique

Comment: @kraego in c++ we can generate a lot of object just using 4 symbols literals. I'm looking for something similar in c#. But me really don't need only 2 bits, it's can be 1 or 2 bytes. I'm searching best way to do this.

Comment: @phuzi yes, but I try to keep the packet size within 1500 bytes. And my current implementation is bad, for now I just get type name and serialize it as string. But 1 char value takes 2 bytes - it's not ok for me.

Comment: But why? Is there a real penalty for exceeding this "magic" value?

Comment: @phuzi yes, but it's not magic value, it's network specification. Many Ethernet network controllers supports up to 9000 bytes, but a lot of not. and if you exceed this value, then there will already be two packets, just the second one will occupy the network.

Comment: If you want two bytes than use int16.

Comment: @jdwend I can use just a number, something like short types. But it's not convenient. If I use numbers as Id, me will need to remember which id's assign to concrete class. But it's a variant which I've already thought about.

Comment: Why worry about the number of packets that you're using to send data? Are you targetting a particulary slow connection or is it too expensive?

Comment: Again, I'm going to say that this sounds like premature optimisation and you're potentially worrying about something that isn't yet a problem.

Comment: @phuzi I'm focusing on a high-load server.

Comment: And are you experiencing any performance issues?

Comment: Like Donald Knuth said, start optimizing when u re running into problems. http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @phuzi i'm not using my serialization system to the full. For now a lot of values serialized with standard size, but I can serialize any values in compact size and that is good. I don't have any performance issues, but 2 bytes for 1 char it's not ok. Do you agree?

Comment: @phuzi and if my class named GodObjectWichCanDestoroyWorld - it 58 bytes.

Comment: 2 bytes is standard for a UTF-16/UCS-2 character, 4 for UTF-32. Unless you are actually running in to a problem then you're wasting your time worrying about stuff that isn't currently a problem rather than just getting the application working.

Comment: If you are so concerned with the efficiency of transmitting an entire object over the wire, then you probably shouldn't be transmitting the entire object over the wire and instead should have a more compact bespoke binary protocol.

Comment: _"i'm not using my serialization system to the full"_ Does it really matter. I would bet there are features in libraries that are only ever used in a tiny fraction of applications that use the library. Don't worry about it until it becomes an issue.

Comment: @DavidG That sounds like what OP is attemtping to do.

Comment: @phuzi I worry about it, because my class id takes 1/2 - 1/3 of object size. For what?

Comment: @phuzi I don't think it is though. For an efficient protocol, you shouldn't be relying on classes at all, just a well-defined message structure e.g. `<command><length><data><terminator>`

Comment: @DavidG yeah, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare IDs for all your types, either using attributes or in a separate list or enum. You can use a variable length encoding, like [LEB128/Base128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128) to only use as many bytes as you need. But if you assign static IDs *you* will be responsible for ensuring ids are unique. A random globally unique ID will need more bits to ensure uniqueness, and will be impossible to compress.

Of course, there is no need to write this yourself. Protobuf already supports base128 encoded integers, and there are easy to use libraries like protobuf.net that handle polymorphism by just assigning attributes with unique ids. It will probably also be faster, more reliable, and easier to use than a custom solution.

But if you are concerned about data size you should look into compression. While things like varint can help, compression will typically provide more benefit. With an efficient algorithm, a verbose serialization format like json can compress to a similar size as an compressed binary file. If you want something fast you might take a look at performance oriented algorithms like [lz4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)).